# django forms real time choose values fields

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax, django

I've created a simple django form and all work fine.
My problem is the choose field andress,I would like to get 
dynamic values(real time from table andress) without need to refresh the page any time to
get last fields changes values.

How can i do this using AJAX or maybe to create a JSON  url with data from table andress
and form get values from json ?

someone to help me ?

models.py

```
class andress(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    field_2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    field_3 = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)


class customer(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=254,blank=True, null=True)
    andress_field= models.ForeignKey('andress', blank=True)
    createddate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

forms.py

```
class customerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    andress_field= forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=andress.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = customer
        fields = (_all_)
```

views.py

```
def add_customer(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = customerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            note = form.save(commit=False)
            note.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/customer/success/')
    else:
        form = customerForm()
    return render(request, 'add_customer.html',{'form':form})
```

html :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
      {{ form }}
</table>
<input value="add" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want exactly and it's not clear what you've tried. If you search for 'django populate field using ajax' you'll find multiple results here on SO that would give you some first steps. Please make a minimum effort to research before asking.

Comment: @dirkgroten is clear that i want,i need to have dynamic chooses fields in html pages using AJAX or json….in my example is not dynamic the user need refresh the page to update the values fields

Comment: but when the user loads the page, the values are fetched so they are fresh from the database. is the user going to stay so long on the page that the values have changed? how often should the values be fetched?

Comment: and again, do some research, there are dozens of posts on SO that explain how to fetch data with ajax and django.

Comment: @dirkgroten user visit this page and have 5 select options in choose field,if other user add new entry then the first user to see that new entry value need to update the page,i don't want this update